# What does the following Cayley diagram mean in Pinter's "A Book of Abstract Algebra"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cayley-graphs

There is a problem in Pinter's "A Book of Abstract Algebra" (Chpt 9 Exercise D4) that has the following picture (some arbitrary group's Cayley Diagram representation):

[image: Hexagon Without Arrows]

In fact, this picture is literally on the *cover* of Pinter's Second Edition book. Based on my experience with Cayley Diagrams...I am pretty confused. I want to assume this is an error, but, once again, it is literally on the cover of the book (so I'm fairly skeptical about this being a *wrong* drawing).

This diagram is effectively saying that the element $a \in G$ is its own inverse...but also that $a \circ a = b \neq e$.

Should there be unidirectional arrows (either clockwise or counter-clockwise) on this drawing? ... Or is this just something that is implicitly understood within the math community? Thanks for the sanity check.

Edit 1: Just as a side note, I am operating off of the convention that Pinter states earlier in his book which is, "**It is also convention that if $a^2 = e$, then no arrow head is used**"...found on pages 51-52.

Edit 2:

[image: Other picture]

I have included this picture to address one of the answers presented by Verret...who tried to offer an alternative interpretation to the above drawing. i.e. I do not think Pinter is trying to indicate $S_3$ with the initial picture...because he correctly depicts $S_3$ in the second picture.

Edit 3: I will include the full problem, by request. The objective is to determine which of the 4 cayley diagrams (if any) are isomorphic to one another.

[image: third edit]

Comment: This seems like a fine representation of $\mathbb{Z}_6$, with generating set $\{-1,1\}$. Why do you think it says that an element is its own inverse?

Comment: I thought when there were no arrows the implication was that the element is equal to its own inverse (i.e. by convention, the exclusion of arrows implies that $a \circ a =e$

Comment: The definition I'm familiar with is that there is that $(g, gs)$ is an edge for all $g \in G$ and $s \in S$ for a generating set $S$. This would mean that if $S$ is closed under inverses, then the graph is undirected. Is this the same definition that you are using?

Comment: This is the quote in Pinter's book (I added it at the bottom of the question):"It is also convention that if $a^2=e$, then no arrow head is used"...which is, as you know, equivalent to saying $a=a^{-1}$

Comment: @AnthonyTer Some people use the convention that if $s$ and $s^{-1}$ are both in $S$, then we get a pair of directed edges, rather than a single undirected one.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the convention that no arrow means the corresponding generator is an involution, than this must be a diagram for $S_3$, which is generated by two involutions (and is the only group of order $6$ with this property).

So indeed, $a^2=e$, but I don't see why you think that $a^2=b\neq e$. There are TWO generators, $a$ and $b$ (corresponding to, say, $(12)$ and $(23)$ in $S_3$), and, in cyclic order, the element are $1-a-ab-aba=bab-ba-b$.

Comment: Sorry if I am misunderstanding your terminology, but I don't think this is correct either. I think Pinter actually depicts what you're describing by using different styled lines. I'll update my question with this picture...because I think that is what you are describing.

Comment: I put up the picture that I think you are describing.

Comment: Could you be a bit clearer? Why is the second picture "correct" (for $S_3$) but not the first one. What is the convention Pinter uses?

Comment: The line styles are indicative of different generators. The second picture has two different line styles...one for each generator (of the 2 that are present...i.e. a and b). The first picture only has one line style, which means there is only one total generator for the group (as opposed to 2). That is my understanding, at least.

Comment: If you have both the convention that different generators have different styles, and that inverse-pairs get arrows, then it is not possible to have two undirected edges with the same style incident with a single vertex.

Comment: Hence my confusion lol. It seems like the initial picture is therefore an error...which is just surprising, seeing as it is the book's cover photo.

Comment: Does it explicitly claim it's a Cayley diagram though?

Comment: Yes, it does. I can put a third edit up of the full question/prompt from the book.

Comment: I have uploaded the full prompt.

Comment: Is it possible that they have the convention that they replace a pair of inverse edges by an undirected edge? That is quite common.